# AWS EC2 Server Recommendation for StartUp that Uses Flask

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am soon launching a web application with the intention of making a profit off membership sales. The application uses Flask (I already tested deploying using Elastic Beanstalk). I also make use of RDS because I use a MySQL database.

I am trying to figure out my server needs. The application mostly just redirects to different pages and occasionally evaluates a Keras machine learning model. This will at first have 0 users as I am just starting.

What do you think is an appropriate EC2 instance for this task? I am currently using Free Tier t2.micro for testing, but am trying to plan for the future. I want to make sure it can handle let's say 20-100 users as the same time. Am I better off staying in the Free tier?

I will provide more information if requested. I am a beginner in all AWS-related concepts, so I am still uncertain about what I should do after looking at online tutorials. I figured a T2 would make most sense because it is cheap and general purpose. I am not sure about what size I need though.

Comment: Use the free t2.micro until it's not enough for you. You can use t2 unlimited. If the t2 micro can't keep up change to t3 small / medium / large etc as required. Alternately you could scale out if flash support horizontal scaling.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Two follow-ups. How does one know when an instance can't "keep up"? Also, why do you suggest t3 small and not t2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use t2.micro until it runs out of capacity or doesn't meet your needs. If you just need more CPU you can enable t2 unlimited, which effectively lets you pay for more CPU credits.

At some point a t2.micro won't keep up. You'll know this because performance will drop, you'll not have enough CPU, or you won't have enough RAM, most of which you can work out with CloudWatch. When this happens your main options are to:

- Get a single larger instance
- Scale out horizontally. Add a load balancer, have more than one instance. This gives you fault tolerance if your application can support horizontal scaling. You're often better off with M (general purpose) instances rather than T series behind a load balancer, as when the T series runs out of CPU credits performance drops - unless you have t2 / t3 unlimited enabled.

When you upgrade I would go to the t3 series rather than t2 as performance is better and the price is lower than t2. You also have the option of t3a (AMD) which is 10% cheaper but can be a [bit slower](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/aws-amazon-web-services/benchmark-aws-ec2-a-series-amd-epyc-instances-t3a-m5a-t3-m5-t2/) for some workloads.

Comment: Alright, so I will regularly monitor CPU usage and such and then determine whether I need more power. Thanks!

Comment: CloudWatch can monitor CPU usage for you, and alert for example if it's over 75% for 3 cycles of 5 minutes, or hits 100%. You would be better off monitoring CPU credits. You'd want an alert if they hit maybe 50% and 10%. If you turn on t2 / t3 unlimited you get billed rather than having your server throttled, but only if your usage is 24 hours is higher than the baseline load. If you don't understand the T2 / T3 CPU model [read up on it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances.html).